# Recursively number directories

Tags: command-line, directory, find, rename, directory-structure

I have the following directory structure:

```
$ directory tree Data
Data
├── Mercury
├── Venus
├── Earth
│   ├── Australia
│   └── Asia
│     └── Japan
|       └── Hokkido   
├── Mars
    ├── HellasBasin
    └── SyrtisCrater
```

How can rename/number/label all the directories recursively to get a result similar to the following?

```
Data
    ├── 01
    ├── 02
    ├── 03
    │   ├── 031
    │   └── 032
    │     └── 0321
    |       └── 03211   
    ├── 04
        ├── 041
        └── 042
```

The idea is to rename the whole tree with new names (numbers, letters or combination of them). They don't necessary have to have labels like 03211.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Now this is an interesting variant on a usually boring subject :)

Comment: Is there actually a locale in which planet names sort in solar-system order... or did you make up that `tree` listing?

Comment: @ Jacob : I spent several hours trying to do this myself before deciding to bother you guys :) I'm new to Linux. This is beyond my current knowledge and skills.

Comment: @ steeldriver : I made that up for this question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using bash:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
rename_count ()
{
    count=1
    for i in *
    do
        new="$1$count"
        mv "$i" "$new"
        # if a directory, recurse into it.
        [[ -d "$new" ]] && (cd "$new"; rename_count "$new")
        ((count++))
    done
}
shopt -s nullglob
cd "$1"
rename_count ""
```

Initially:

```
$ tree foo
foo
├── a
│   ├── d
│   │   └── g
│   ├── e
│   │   └── g
│   └── f
│       └── g
├── b
│   ├── d
│   │   └── g
│   ├── e
│   │   └── g
│   └── f
│       └── g
└── c
    ├── d
    │   └── g
    ├── e
    │   └── g
    └── f
        └── g

12 directories, 9 files
```

Then:

```
$ ./foo.sh foo
$ tree foo
foo
├── 1
│   ├── 11
│   │   └── 111
│   ├── 12
│   │   └── 121
│   └── 13
│       └── 131
├── 2
│   ├── 21
│   │   └── 211
│   ├── 22
│   │   └── 221
│   └── 23
│       └── 231
└── 3
    ├── 31
    │   └── 311
    ├── 32
    │   └── 321
    └── 33
        └── 331

12 directories, 9 files
```

Comment: @steeldriver it could, and I'll add that. Thanks!