# How can I rename a directory tree to match a tree saved in a file?

Tags: scripts, directory, rename, batch, directory-structure

I have an old directory-tree-file created using `find . -type d >old.txt`. Now I want to rename an existing tree that has the same exact structure to mach the old tree. This question is related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007062/recursively-numer-directories/1007079#1007079)

In other words:
How can I **convert the following:**

```
NEW
    ├── 01
    ├── 02
    ├── 03
    │   ├── 031
    │   └── 032
    │     └── 0321
    |       └── 03211   
    ├── 04
        ├── 041
        └── 042
```

**back to this:**

```
OLD
├── Mercury
├── Venus
├── Earth
│   ├── Australia
│   └── Asia
│     └── Japan
|       └── Hokkido   
├── Mars
    ├── HellasBasin
    └── SyrtisCrater
```

using my old.txt (directory-tree), or using some other script **without touching any files** in the directories?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is nothing that will do this *after* you only have the old directory tree as file and no way to correlate the new directory names with the old ones.

How would the script know if `01`correlates to `Mercury` or `Venus` ?

There is, however, this [Unix StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144779/271588) to exactly the same question, where OP wrote [a Perl script](https://sourceforge.net/p/sdaaubckp/code/HEAD/tree/single-scripts/revrs-tree.pl#l41) himself, since no one could provide an answer.

But I think for this to work, you do need the old directries intact, since it runs tree with options

`tree --dirsfirst -spugD`

Comment: Thank you for the input. Being a recent convert to Linux/Unix I might sound very ignorant, but I thought some Linux genius could come up with some script to match the directory locations (location identity if there's anything like that) and do the renaming. Both trees have the same number of directories at the same locations and the same exact hierarchy. I have the old directories intact...

Comment: If you have the old directories, try the Perl script

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've been studying the script. I'm still hopeful that someone would come up with a simpler bash script.

Comment: okay, as I see it, its not simple. Forgive the question, but why not copy over the whole folder to the new host ?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Yes, I will have no other choice if this is not going to work. I'll got to test that perl script. Thanks for taking the time to help me though.

Comment: I don't know what kind of filesizes and numbers you have there, but `rsync` does a fantastic job of copying things from one place to another

Comment: I use rsync for all my file copying and backup purposes. It would have been a great tip if I didn't know about rsync. And, by the way, I found to way to achieve my goal without any complex scripts. My method involves excel (I use Libreoffice calc). I got both trees in a script like this: find ./ -type d -execdir sh -c 'cd "{}" &&   mv   ./03211   ./Hokkido' \;. And reaped for each directory in a bash script. Works like a charm...